# How do I determine the number of values assumed by a "repeating" function in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I have a function

```
f :: Eq a => a -> a
```

which I know eventually repeats itself (I'm not quite sure what such a function is called; "periodic" comes to mind, but that's a bit different, isn't it), and I want to determine how many unique values it produces.

Naively, something like

```
import Data.List (nub)
length $ nub $ take n $ iterate f a0
```

where `a0` is some initial `a` and `n` is some large number that I know exceeds the number of unique values for `f`, will work. But, in addition to having the obvious drawback that I must guess or trial-and-error `n`, this is impractical (in my case, anyway) because `f` can be time-consuming.

What is the best way to find the list of unique value produced by recurring application of such a "repeating" (or whatever the correct term is) function in Haskell?

Comment: If `f :: a -> a` is the whole type then all this function can do is to either raise an error or return its argument. Assuming its not doing something magical I'd tell `f = id`.

Comment: surely you want `Eq a => a -> a` right? without it you cannot even tell if `f a == f b` for some `a,b`, and you really want `cycleLength :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> Integer` I guess?

Comment: @Carsten: Yes, I should have specified that (it is the case). Fixed.

Comment: in this case you can do some very basic (really bad perfomance) stuff by iterative adding values to a list till you hit an existing element and then get the length of it I guess

Comment: @Carsten: Not sure about `cycleLength` (or where to find it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is literally exactly the problem addressed by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection .  That page specifies several well-known solutions to that problem.

Here's an untested Haskell implementation of the basic tortoise-and-hare algorithm:

```
floyd :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> (Int, Int)
floyd f x0 = (lam, mu) where
  hare0 = head
    [t | (h, t) <- tail $ zip (iterate f x0) (iterate (f . f) x0), h == t]
  (mu, tortoise1) = head 
    [(m, t) | (m, t, h) <- zip3 [0..] (iterate f x0) (iterate f hare0), t == h]
  lam = head [l | (l, h) <- zip [1..] (iterate f (f tortoise1)), h == tortoise1]
```

Comment: Looks like you're the last man standing: All the other answers have vanished (and didn't work). Help!

Comment: The linked article outlines some algorithms for the problem pretty clearly.  Have you tried implementing them?

Comment: No, not in the few minutes since I asked the question.

Comment: Can you add more to this answer than just a link?

Comment: and the answer to the OP's question seems to be: `mu + lam`.

Comment: I think this does more work than necessary to answer OP's question, though.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is the very basic idea I was commenting about:

```
import Data.List(unfoldr, genericLength)

cycleLen :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> Integer
cycleLen f a0 = 1 + genericLength (unfoldr gen [a0])
  where gen xs@(x:_) =
          let a' = f x
          in if a' `elem` xs then Nothing else Just (a',a':xs)
        gen [] = undefined
```

let's test it with some very basic function:

```
test :: Int -> Int
test x = (x*2+1) `mod` 10

λ> cycleLen test 0
5
λ> take 6 (iterate test 0)
[0,1,3,7,5,1]

λ> cycleLen test 4
2
λ> take 6 (iterate test 4)
[4,9,9,9,9,9]
```

seems fine ;)

but beware: it's surely not the optimal way to do it - but it works for small stuff I guess

Comment: That's certainly faster than what I was doing (and seems to work)!

Comment: still the algorithms you'll find in the wiki article Louis linked will be a lot faster ;)

Comment: An "obvious" improvement is to use something like `Data.Set` for the "accumulator" instead of a list (requires an `Ord` constraint though). Also note that a full `unfoldr` isn't necessary unless you need the lazily produced list: just the take the length of the final accumulater.